# Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, nsstring, nsdate

I am setting up some constants, one being an NSDate but receiving this wanring message:

Incompatible pointer types initializing `NSDate *const __strong` with an expression of type `NSString`

Simple explanation of code (imp file):

```
NSDate *const kPAPUserBirthdayKey = @"fbBirthday";
```

Advanced explanation:
I use a constants file as a singleton holding constant variables for the API i write to. For example the above which is a Date field which will hold the facebook users birthday when connecting to Facebook.

This is then later used in the following conversion:

```
// Convert the DOB string into Date format
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate* userDOB = [df dateFromString:user.birthday];
[[PFUser currentUser] setObject:userDOB forKey:kPAPUserBirthdayKey];
```

Can someone explain what the warning actually means and what should be changed here? I get the same error on the last line of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDate *const kPAPUserBirthdayKey = @"fbBirthday";
```

You are assigning a string to a NSDate.

Change `NSDate` to `NSString`.

**Use:**

```
NSString const *kPAPUserBirthdayKey = @"fbBirthday";
```

Also check what you need ?

[A constant pointer or pointer to a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091825/constant-pointer-vs-pointer-on-a-constant-value).

Comment: @CarlVeazey: sorry yet again typo miss, explained good but copied and forgot to change nsdate to nsstring :( And you are very frequent to downvote. NO mercy what so ever.

Comment: Ok, I guess this relates more to how this is being used/implemented. fbBirthday is a string correct however that is simply the title/column the date will then be input into. So the actual data being input would be a Date, shown here - [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:userDOB forKey:kPAPUserBirthdayKey];

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *const kPAPUserBirthdayKey                               = @"fbBirthday";
```

Here `fbBirthday` is a string not date. The warning says that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your constant's type to NSString. The compiler is telling you you're making an assignment between incompatible types, as NSString is not a subclass of NSDate.