# Constant pointer vs Pointer to constant

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I want to know the difference between

```
const int* ptr;
```

and

```
int * const ptr;
```

and how it works.

It is pretty difficult for me to understand or keep remember this.
Please help.

Comment: Read Chapter 3. Unscrambling Declarations in C of the book Deep C Secrets by Peter linden, you will learn how to decipher any complex decalration with any combinations of pointers, constants etc

Comment: The dupe is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/890535/694576 not where it had been close for, as the latter is about C++.

Comment: @user694733 on the other side it gives me a feeling as to how much developers want to contribute to the community that status of the question doesn't matter to them........at times :)

Answer (score 468, accepted):

```
const int* ptr;
```

declares `ptr` a pointer to `const int` type. You can modify `ptr` itself but the object pointed to by `ptr` shall not be modified.

```
const int a = 10;
const int* ptr = &a;  
*ptr = 5; // wrong
ptr++;    // right
```

While

```
int * const ptr;
```

declares `ptr` a `const` pointer to `int` type. You are not allowed to modify `ptr` but the object pointed to by `ptr` can be modified.

```
int a = 10;
int *const ptr = &a;  
*ptr = 5; // right
ptr++;    // wrong
```

Generally I would prefer the declaration like this which make it easy to read and understand (read from right to left):

```
int const  *ptr; // ptr is a pointer to constant int 
int *const ptr;  // ptr is a constant pointer to int
```

Comment: in second case of of constant pointer can't we point to `NULL` after initilzation?

Comment: @Jayesh; No, you can't.

Comment: Suppose constant pointer pointed to some memory and we are freeing that memory. After that is it possible to assign with `NULL`? If not then i think every constant pointer are dangling pointer right?

Comment: @Jayesh; What is the purpose of `const` pointer?

Comment: *const* pointer we use to make sure not to change address pointed by it.

Comment: But i would like to say that if we use *const* pointer then it's not true that we are not going to free memory pointed by it.

Comment: @Jayesh; I never said that.

Comment: I feel there should be some other term for `int* const`. I believe the whole world including the OP calls it `Pointer to a constant` while the value pointed to by such a pointer isn't a constant but a variable. It is just that the pointer becomes a constant after it is assigned an address during its initialization. I don't know why it is like that.

Comment: I just realized that even this code `int i = 10; const int* ptr = &i;` works. which means `ptr` doesn't have to point to a constant value always. You can also point to a variable value through it. It is just that you will never be able to modify the value pointed by `ptr`.

Comment: Even if it's a duplicate, this answer is by far the best...

Comment: It would have been nice had they flipped that declaration to make it more human-readable and intuitive.

Comment: Regarding the fact that I access this page very often, is there any analogy you do in your head in order to better retain the difference ? It would be great if you could tell us!

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu Analogy is the last two lines of the answer. That's how I retain it. If you are having any problem in deciphering complex pointer declarations like `void ( *( *f[] ) () ) ()`, then I would suggest you to go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34560439/2455888) in which I explained how to understand any complex pointer declaration using a gif. If you have any specific problem then you can type in here and I will try to explain.

Comment: can I do `const int * const a`?

Comment: @JinKwon Of course you can do but it will have an entirely different meaning.

Comment: @haccks which means...?

Comment: @JinKwon `const int * const a` declares `a` as *`const` pointer to a `const int`*. In this case neither `a` shall be modified nor the object pointed to by `a` through `*a`.

Answer (score 52):

```
const int * ptr;
```

means that the pointed data is constant and immutable but the pointer is not.

```
int * const ptr;
```

means that the pointer is constant and immutable but the pointed data is not.

Comment: a pointer to `const` doesn't say anything about whether the object to which the pointer points is `const`. Defining a pointer as a pointer to `const` affects only what we can do with the pointer.

Answer (score 16):

**1) Constant Pointers :** These type of pointers are the one which cannot change address they are pointing to. This means that suppose there is a pointer which points to a variable (or stores the address of that variable). Now if we try to point the pointer to some other variable (or try to make the pointer store address of some other variable), then constant pointers are incapable of this.

A constant pointer is declared as : `int *const ptr` ( the location of 'const' make the pointer 'ptr' as constant pointer)

**2) Pointer to Constant :** These type of pointers are the one which cannot change the value they are pointing to. This means they cannot change the value of the variable whose address they are holding.

A pointer to a constant is declared as : `const int *ptr` (the location of 'const' makes the pointer 'ptr' as a pointer to constant.

**Example**

**Constant Pointer**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {10,11};
    int* const ptr = a;

    *ptr = 11;

    printf("\n value at ptr is  : [%d]\n",*ptr);
    printf("\n Address pointed by ptr  : [%p]\n",(unsigned int*)ptr);

    ptr++;
    printf("\n Address pointed by ptr  : [%p]\n",(unsigned int*)ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, when we compile the above code, compiler complains :

```
practice # gcc -Wall constant_pointer.c -o constant_pointer
constant_pointer.c: In function ‘main’:
constant_pointer.c:13: error: increment of read-only variable ‘ptr’
```

Hence we see very clearly above that compiler complains that we cannot changes the address held by a constant pointer.

**Pointer to Constants**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    const int* ptr = &a;


    printf("\n value at ptr is  : [%d]\n",*ptr);
    printf("\n Address pointed by ptr  : [%p]\n",(unsigned int*)ptr);

    *ptr = 11;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, when the above code is compiled, the compiler complains :

```
practice # gcc -Wall pointer_to_constant.c -o pointer_to_constant
pointer_to_constant.c: In function ‘main’:
pointer_to_constant.c:12: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*ptr’
```

Hence here too we see that compiler does not allow the pointer to a constant to change the value of the variable being pointed.

[Quotation](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/difference-constant-pointers-pointer-t26816/)

Answer (score 12):

Referencing
<kbd>[**This Thread**](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/c-constant-pointers/)</kbd>

**Constant Pointers**

Lets first understand what a constant pointer is. A constant pointer is a pointer that cannot change the address its holding. In other words, we can say that once a constant pointer points to a variable then it cannot point to any other variable.

A constant pointer is declared as follows :
`<type of pointer> * const <name of pointer>` 
An example declaration would look like :
`int * const ptr;` 
Lets take a small code to illustrate these type of pointers :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int var1 = 0, var2 = 0;
    int *const ptr = &var1;
    ptr = &var2;
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above example :

- We declared two variables var1 and var2
- A constant pointer ‘ptr’ was declared and made to point var1
- Next, ptr is made to point var2.
- Finally, we try to print the value ptr is pointing to.

---

**Pointer to Constant**

As evident from the name, a pointer through which one cannot change the value of variable it points is known as a pointer to constant. These type of pointers can change the address they point to but cannot change the value kept at those address.

A pointer to constant is defined as :
`const <type of pointer>* <name of pointer>`
An example of definition could be :
`const int* ptr;` 
Lets take a small code to illustrate a pointer to a constant :

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int var1 = 0;
    const int* ptr = &var1;
    *ptr = 1;
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

In the code above :

- We defined a variable var1 with value 0
- we defined a pointer to a constant which points to variable var1
- Now, through this pointer we tried to change the value of var1
- Used printf to print the new value.

Comment: i genrally don't do the home-work...`url answers` are not suggested mate...post answers next time, not the url...+1 though !! :)

Comment: You should mention that these are non-compiling examples, not examples of correct usage.

Answer (score 11):

```
const int* ptr;
```

is a pointer to constant (content). You are allowed to modify the pointer. e.g. `ptr = NULL`, `ptr++`, but modification of the content is *not* possible.

```
int * const ptr;
```

Is a constant pointer. The opposite is possible. You are **not** allowed to modify the pointer, but you *are* allowed to modify what it points to e.g. `*ptr += 5`.

Answer (score 7):

```
int i;
int j;

int * const ptr1 = &i;
```

The compiler will stop you changing `ptr1`.

```
const int * ptr2 = &i;
```

The compiler will stop you changing `*ptr2`.

```
ptr1 = &j; // error
*ptr1 = 7; // ok

ptr2 = &j; // ok
*ptr2 = 7; // error
```

Note that you can still change `*ptr2`, just not by literally typing `*ptr2`:

```
i = 4;
printf("before: %d\n", *ptr2); // prints 4
i = 5;
printf("after: %d\n", *ptr2); // prints 5
*ptr2 = 6; // still an error
```

You can also have a pointer with both features:

```
const int * const ptr3 = &i;

ptr3 = &j; // error
*ptr3 = 7; // error
```

Comment: Very good clarification about "pointer to constant int". It is not allowed to edit "int" via pointer, however it is allowed to edit "int" via some other way.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the following link for better understanding about the difference between Const pointer and Pointer on a constant value.

[constant pointer vs pointer on a constant value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091825/constant-pointer-vs-pointer-on-a-constant-value)

Answer (score 2):

`const int* ptr;`   here think like *ptr is constant and *ptr can't be change again

`int * const ptr;`  while here think like ptr as a constant and that can't be change again