# Eclipse CDT isConst check

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a simple Pointer.c file:

```
#include<stdio.h>

// Pointer To Constant
const int* ptrToConst ;


//Constant Pointer
int* const ConstPtr ;
```

When I parse it through Eclipse CDT:

```
File f = new File("C:/Data/Pointer.c");
IASTTranslationUnit ast = ASTProvider.getInstance().getASTWithoutCache(f);

for (IASTDeclaration d : ast.getDeclarations()) {

  IASTSimpleDeclaration sd = (IASTSimpleDeclaration) d;
  System.out.println("Variable Name: " + sd.getDeclarators()[0].getName());
  System.out.println("Is Constant: " + sd.getDeclSpecifier().isConst() + "\n");
}
```

The output is:

```
Variable Name: ptrToConst
Is Constant: true

Variable Name: ConstPtr
Is Constant: false
```

As per the output, the first variable which is pointer to constant is parsed as **constant** while the other one, a constant pointer is not. I don't understand this behavior, why is it so? Does CDT understand the pointer variables differently? As per my understanding the output should be the exactly reverse of it.

Check the variable d detail for 2nd case at the time of debugging:

[image]

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the line with the `for` loop and find out where in the abstract syntax tree (`ast`) the information about the `const` modifier of the second case is hold.

Comment: I tried it, but I'm not getting such info. Where exactly can we look into it? Have added the screenshot of it, please check. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into _declarators > [0] > pointerOps_?

Comment: Just checked, it's coming properly under pointerOps!! Thanks a lot! Could you also please explain the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21476937/6505250))

- `const int* ptrToConst` declares a pointer (that can be modified) to a **constant integer** and
- `int* const ConstPtr` declares a **contant pointer** to an integer (that can be modified),

in the second case `sd.getDeclSpecifier().isConst()` returns `false`.

So in the second case, the **`const` modifier** can be found **deeper in the abstract syntax tree** at the [pointer operators](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/cdt/core/dom/ast/IASTDeclarator.html#getPointerOperators--) instead (as you have found out yourself).