# what's the difference between ros msg::ptr and msg::constPtr?

Tags: c++, ros

I'm confused about the following ROS source code:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::nav_msgs::Odometry_<ContainerAllocator> > Ptr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::nav_msgs::Odometry_<ContainerAllocator> const> ConstPtr;
```

What are their differences and under what circumstances are they suitable for use？I would appreciate it if you could give me some inspiration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476869/constant-pointer-vs-pointer-to-constant

Comment: another one :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const