# How can this code compile?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, constants

```
    const UIView * vLocalBottomButton = self.BottomButton;

    vLocalBottomButton =nil;
```

Basically I want to pass on self.BottomButton to a method that will run at outside the main thread. When the view is used, it'll be done at the main thread.

I just need to ensure that the view doesn't change. That's all. So I put it to a local variable and then pass that local variable to ensure that vLocalBottomButton didn't change.

Answer (score 3):

You should create constant pointer. In your case:

```
UIView * const vLocalBottomButton = self.BottomButton;

//this won't compile therefore

vLocalBottomButton =nil;
```

Comment: Why the pointer is not const? How do you explain this  grammar rules?

Comment: Understand the difference between constant value and constant pointer in C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091825/constant-pointer-vs-pointer-on-a-constant-value