# Difference between const typdef

Tags: c++, c

What is the exact difference between

```
typedef class abc* abcp;  
typedef const class abc* constAbcp ; 

const abcp a1 ;  ------- 1 
constAbcp  a2 ;  ------- 2

what is the difference between 1 and 2
```

Comment: Remove the 'class' keyword; it's pointless and archaic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504411/typedef-pointer-const-weirdness

Comment: Note that hiding data pointers with `typedef` is generally considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

```
a2 is pointer to constant.
a1 is constant pointer.

a2->nonConstFunc(); // Bad
a1 = a2; // Bad

a1->nonConstFunc(); // OK
a2 = new_a2; // OK
```

Example:

```
struct abc {
  int foo;
};

typedef abc* abcp;  
typedef const abc* constAbcp ;

abc temp[5];

const abcp a1 = temp;
constAbcp  a2 = temp;

a1->foo = 5; // OK
a2->foo = 5; // Bad(Compile error)

a1++;  // Bad
a2++; // OK
```

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/pvvd7R)

---

Closely related C question: [what does this 2 const mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074718/c-what-does-this-2-const-mean/27074751#27074751)

Answer (score 0):

```
const abcp a1 ;   
const Abcp  a2 ;
```

`a1` is a pointer to a constant of type `abcp`

`a2` is a constant pointer to a constant of type `Abcp`

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned by the other answerers, `a1` is a constant pointer. Meaning that the *address* cannot be changed.

```
const abcp a1;
```

Simplifies to:

```
abc* const a1;
```

Which frankly is nonsense cause you now have a pointer that is uninitialized and cannot be changed. So any assignment to it is illegal. For example you can't do this: <strike>`a1 = NULL;`</strike>.

Also mentioned by the other answerers, `a2` is a pointer to a constant. Meaning that the *value* addressed cannot be changed.

```
constAbcp a2;
```

Simplifies to:

```
const abc* a2;
```

This does make sense, because you can assign to `a2` all you want, it's just that you can only use it to read the value it references. You cannot use it to write to the value it references.