# Static constant character pointer and why it's used in this fashion

Tags: c++, c, static, char, constants

```
static const char* const test_script = "test_script";
```

When and why would you use a statement such as the one above? 
Does it have any benefits?

Why use a `char*` instead of a constant character?
A "constant Character pointer" (`const char*`) is a constant already and cannot be changed; Then why use the word `static` in the front of it? What good does it do?

Comment: Related: [what does this 2 const mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074718/c-what-does-this-2-const-mean/27074751#27074751). I would prefer `static const char test_script[] = "test_script";`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `const char *p` is *not* a constant pointer. It's a modifiable pointer to a `const char`, that is, to a constant character. You can make the pointer point to something else, but you cannot change the character(s) to which it points. In other words, `p = x` is allowed, but `*p = y` is not.

A `char * const` is the opposite: a constant pointer to a mutable character. `*p = y` is allowed, `p = x` is not.

A `const char * const` is both: a constant pointer to a constant character.

Regarding `static`: this gives the declared variable internal linkage (cannot be accessed by name from outside the source file). Since you're asking about both C and C++, note that this is where they differ.

In C++, a variable declared `const` and not explicitly declared `extern` has internal linkage by default. Since the pointer in question is `const` (I'm talking about the second `const`), the `static` is superfluous in C++ and doesn't do anything.

That's not the case in C, where `const` variables cannot be used as constant expressions and do *not* have internal linkage by default. So in C, the `static` is necessary to give `test_script` internal linkage.

The above discussion of `static` assumes the declaration is at file scope (C) or namespace scope (C++). If it's inside a function, the meaning of `static` changes. Without `static`, it would a normal local variable in the function—each invocation would have its own copy. With `static`, it receives static storage duration and thus persists between function calls—all invocations share that one copy. Since you're asking about both C and C++, I am not going to discuss class scope.

Finally, you asked "why pointer instead of characters." This way, the pointer points to the actual string literal (probably somewhere in the read-only part of the process's memory). One reason to do that would be if you even need to pass `test_script` somewhere where a `const char * const *` (a pointer to a constant pointer to constant character(s)) is expected. Also, if the same string literal appears multiple times in source code, it can be shared.

An alternative would be to declare an array:

```
const char test_script[] = "test_script";
```

This would *copy* the string literal into `test_script`, guaranteeing that it has its own copy of the data. Then you can learn the length at compile-time from `sizeof test_script` (which includes the terminating `NUL`). It will also consume slightly less memory (no need for the pointer) if it's the only occurence of that string literal. However, as it will have its own copy of the data, it cannot share the storage of the string literal (if that is used elsewhere in the code as well).

Comment: The length is `sizeof test_script - 1`.  Declaring this string as a pointer may be useful if somewhere in the program you need to pass the address of a pointer.  It is unlikely but possible that you call a function declared with an argument `const char * const *` or equivalent.

Comment: Assuming @newb7777's `test_script` has file scope and yours does too, then the array uses less memory (exactly `sizeof(char*)` bytes).