# int **const p does not behave like constant

Tags: c++, c, pointers

We know that in int *const p, where p is a constant pointer
it means that address that p holds cannot changed but here in function foo we change the address.

How can it be possible?

```
int main(){
    int i = 10;
    int *p = &i;
    foo(&p);
    printf("%d ", *p);
    printf("%d ", *p);
}
void foo(int **const p){
    int j = 11;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d ", **p);
}
```

Comment: you must need to know the difference between the pointer and value at the pointer. you can't change p but you can change the value at p.

Comment: 'plz explain it in detail' sounds suspiciously homeworky...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const

Comment: Exact dupe of the above.

Comment: @legends2k Right, I missed that. Closed and changed my answer to CW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int **const p` means `p` is constant.

So following are not allowed

```
p++; // Bad
p += 10; // Bad
p = newp; // Bad
```

But following are fine:

```
if(p) *p = some_p;
if(p && *p) **p = some_int;
```

If you want `*p` should not be re-assigned, use the following

```
int * const *p;
```

If you want neither `p` nor `*p` should be changeable, use:

```
int * const * const p;
```

And following will make all `p`, `*p` and `**p` read-only

```
  const int *const *const p;
//  1          2      3
```

1: `**p` is constant
2: `*p` is constant
3: `p` is constant

Use 1 or 2 or 3 or any combination as per your requirement.

cdecl page: How to read complex declarations like [`int ** const p`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int%20**const%20p) and [`const int *const *const p`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=const%20int%20*const%20*const%20p)

Related: [c - what does this 2 const mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074718/c-what-does-this-2-const-mean/27074751)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `const` is applied on `p` itself, not on `* p` or `** p`. In other words, you can change `*p` and `**p`, but you cannot change `p`.

FWIW, try changing the *value* of `p` and see.

See it <kbd>[LIVE](http://ideone.com/pJ0U8i)</kbd>

Comment: prog.c: In function 'foo':
prog.c:17:7: error: assignment of read-only parameter 'p'
     p = &j;

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you were demonstrating only what values could be changed, mb.