# Returning indirect reference to self in const function

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I'm learning to despise `const`.

```
struct b;

struct a {
    b* p;
    void nonConst() { p = nullptr;}
    b* getP() const { return p;}
};
struct b {
    a *p;
    a *getP() const { return p;}
};

void func (const a *ii) {
    b *uRef = ii->getP();

    //dear god, we've just obtained a pointer to a non-const a, starting with const a
    a *iii = uRef->getP();

    //and we've just modified ii, a const object
    iii->nonConst();
}

int main() {
    a *i = new a;
    b *u = new b;
    i->p = u;
    u->p = i;

    func(i);
}
```

Could this induce any undefined behavior? If not, is it breaking any `const` rules? If not that, why is `this` treated as a `const` pointer to `const` data, and not just a `const` pointer to non-`const` data?

Comment: const pointer vs pointer to const - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091825/constant-pointer-vs-pointer-on-a-constant-value

Comment: @MichaelGazonda I understand that and it doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: Just never use `const`. None of the good programmers do. It's just a pain. *cough*

Comment: My advice would be *do use const* ; it will catch many (but not all) errors, and help the compiler to optimize your code.  The problem in this post is that OP hasn't defined the semantics of the relationship between an `a` and the thing that an `a::p` is pointing to.

Comment: @MattMcNabb How would I define the semantics? I don't even know what that means.

Comment: @BWG my answer discusses this. You have to decide whether an object of type `const a` should allow the thing that `p` points to to be modified. Nobody can decide this for you (as posted) because we don't know what problem your code is trying to solve

Comment: As written, `b *p;` means that the thing being pointed to may be modified, even for `p` being a member of a `const a`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb OK, I understand now. I've decided to nuke all const in my object to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `const` variables in your code, so there is no UB.

In `void func (const a *ii)`, the `const` means *`ii` might either be pointing to an `a` or a `const a`, so we shouldn't allow writing through this pointer in case it actually points to a `const a`*.

But in your code it doesn't actually point to a `const a`.

---

The underlying issue you seem to be having is related to the basic structure:

```
struct C
{
    std::string *ptr;
};
```

In this case, if we have a variable:

```
const C c = something;
```

then the question is, should it be permitted to write:

```
*(c.ptr) = "Hello";
```

The rules of C++ say "Yes, this is fine". This is because `c.ptr` is `const`, but the thing being pointed to is not `const`.

The question of whether or not this is actually a good idea is something that you have to decide on as part of your class interface (which you will describe in your class's documentation).

If the value of the string is supposed to be an invariant for instances of `C`, then you may want to disallow this, or at least, discourage it.

Back to your original code, if you want a `const a` to represent holding a `const b`, then you would need to put:

```
b const * getP() const { return p;}
  ^^^^^
```

and then the caller will not be able to write `b *uRef = ii->getP();` , they'd have to at least throw in a `const_cast`.

Finally, there isn't an easy way for a `const a` to actually hold a `b const *`, but a non-const `a` to hold a `b *`. A simpler solution is to actually have two different classes here (say `a` and `const_a`).

Comment: But there are const variables. `ii` is a pointer to a `const`, which means in theory I shouldn't be able to modify what it points to, but I clearly can.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. I'll modify my question. Nah, nevermind, I think I get it.