# What does ... mean in a c function definition

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void ff(const char *format,...)
{
    printf("hr");
}
int main()
{
    ff("d","c");
}
```

I want to know what is the meaning of const char *format,... in my declaration of ff function. Moreover, ff function can be called by passing 1 argument, 2 arguments and n arguments. How this function call is working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [constant pointer vs pointer on a constant value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091825/constant-pointer-vs-pointer-on-a-constant-value)

Comment: I want to know what that ... is? and how this function call is working?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic

Answer (score 4):

`const char *format` declares a parameter which is a pointer to a character and can not be changed. This is a normal way of passing strings in `c`.

The `...` is a declaration of variable arguments, it basically says there will be more arguments to this function, we don't know how many or of what type they will be. See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm for an introduction to variable arguments.