# Why "const int *p is a pointer to a const int" is a wrong explanation but used widely?

Tags: c++, c

Many materials mention that

> `const int *p` is a pointer to a const int.

I really don't think so and don't get this point because `const int *p` just means that:

**the value of the object p point to cannot be changed by dereferencing p**.

It does not mean:

**the object p points to need to be a const.**

Example:

```
int a = 5;
const int *p = &a;
```

This code is totally valid and we don't need `const int a = 5`

So Why that wrong explanation is used widely?

Comment: And it's a pointer :)

Comment: @LogicStuff; His question is legit. Not a dupe with the question you provided a link for.

Comment: I think the real reason would be hard to determine, but I guess people started using that definition because it kind of worked, and then it stuck.

Comment: [`const char *` a does not mean that the pointed data is constant and immutable. It means just that the pointer cannot write to it.](https://gist.github.com/andyli/b4107c8910208fe54764)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [constant pointer vs pointer on a constant value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091825/constant-pointer-vs-pointer-on-a-constant-value)

Comment: @GNKeshava Why are you repeating what OP is stating in the question?

Comment: Google "const correctness". If you have no intention to modify a variable, why make it possible?

Comment: The type of something doesn't tell you much of anything about its value and what a pointer points to is its value. The type of `const int *p` is "pointer to const int" because when you dereference it, you get a thing of type `const int`.

Answer (score 2):

There is not really any such thing as references/pointers to constant objects in C, only read-only references to objects.  This is confusing, because the qualifier for read-only objects is `const`.  Many textbooks and tutorials seem to gloss over this fact, as you've observed.

The closest you can come is `const X *restrict p`, which declares `p` as pointing to an object which cannot be changed through `p` (because `const`) and must *only* be accessed through `p` (because `restrict`).  However, the compiler does not enforce `restrict`, it just might give you the wrong code if you use `restrict` incorrectly.

So you are back to square one.  There is not really any such thing as a "reference to a constant object" in C, and it is somewhat unfortunate that we use `const` to mean something else.

Comment: Not my down-vote (I don't know enough C), but this makes me realise this is the kind of question that should only be tagged C or C++, but not both.

Comment: There is `const int* const ptr = &obj` which cannot be changed to point at other objects. If `obj` is `const int`, then `ptr` absolutely points to a `const int`. Still, this is a result of the instruction sequence. It is absolutely true that the **C type system** cannot express "pointer to const int".

Answer (score 0):

> This code is totally valid and we don't need `const int a = 5`

Actually we need. In the snippet

```
int a = 5;
const int *p = &a;
```

you shall not modify `a` by using `*p` but `a`

```
a = 10;
```

Here `const int *p` only meant that program can’t use the expression `*p` to alter the value of any objects that `*p` might designate.

Comment: You're not answering the question. OP already knows what `const int* p` really means.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question.  I think OP is asking why `const int *` can point to an `int`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp; *why `const int *` can point to an `int`*: that's because `const int *` only promise that the object this pointer points can't be modified using this pointer.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the OP is confused about what `const int *` means, but rather the question is about the underlying rationale / logic / reasoning in the C standard for not supporting pointers to constant objects (which is not what a `const int *` is).

Answer (score -3):

When you have const int * a it means that the value stored at address "a" it cannot be change .

```
int a = 5;
const int *p = &a;
*p=10; /* When you try this you will raise an error because you try to change
the value of a read only location*/
```