# template deduction: const reference and const pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, reference, template-argument-deduction

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t)
{}

int x = 1;
const int & rx = x;
const int * px = &x;
f(rx); // t is int
f(px); // t is const int *, instead of int *, WHY???
```

I'm confused now. According to **Effective Modern c++**,

> It’s important to recognize that const is ignored only for by-value
>   parameters. As we’ve seen, for parameters that are references-to- or
>   pointers-to-const, the constness of expr is preserved during type
>   deduction.

I think it means

```
template <typename T>
void f(T * t)
{}
f(px); // t is const int *

template <typename T>
void f(T & t)
{}
f(cx); // t is const int &

template <typename T>
void f(T t)
{}
f(value); // const or volatile of value will be ignored when the type of the parameter t is deduced
```

So I think when `f(px)` above, `t` should be `int *`, but in fact it is `const int *`.

Why the `const` of reference is ignored but the `const` of pointer isn't?
Or, why isn't `rx` `const int &`?

Comment: Re: "why isn't `rx` `const int &`?": It can be, if you write `f<const int &>(rx)` (whereas `f<int &>(rx)` would not be valid). But then, for that matter, you can also write `f<const int &>(x)`. So the ref-ness of `rx` is not relevant to template argument deduction; it's treated the same as if it were just a `const int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I think when `f(px)` above, `px` should be `int *`, but in fact it is `const int *`.

The point is the type of parameter, behaviors change for *passed-by-value* and *passed-by-reference/pointer*.

When passed-by-value, the constness of the argument itself is ignored. For a pointer parameter, the constness of pointer is ignored (const pointer -> pointer), but the constness of pointee is still preserved (pointer to const -> pointer to const).

It does make sense because when pass a pointer, the pointer itself is copied, but the pointee is the same, they're both pointing to the same thing, so constness of pointee is preserved; from the point of callers, they won't want the object to be modified, they might use it later. While pass a reference (reference doesn't matter in fact here), you'll get a brand new value copied, which has nothing to do with the original one, then constness is ignored.

As the following explanations in the book, when const pointer to const (a `const char* const`) passed,

```
template<typename T>
void f(T param); // param is still passed by value

const char* const ptr = // ptr is const pointer to const object
  "Fun with pointers";

f(ptr); // pass arg of type const char * const
```

The type deduced for `param` will be `const char*`.

Comment: I'm confused because I thought the constness of reference should be preserved too. In my example, I thought `rx` sould be `const int &`, instead of `int`. I always regard reference is kind of the same thing with pointer. Well, I'm wrong.

Comment: @Thomas The difference is that when you pass a pointer, the pointer itself is copied, but the pointee is the same, they're both pointing to the same thing, so constness of pointee is preserved. While you pass a reference, you'll get a brand new value copied, which has nothing to do with the original one, then constness is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Only top-level const/volatile qualifiers are ignored. All others are inherent qualities of your type. In other words, you're copying a pointer - it means the function operates on a copy and any modifications to it (like assigning another variable's address) do not modify the original pointer. But if you pass a pointer to *const int*, having the function modify the integer is very much counter-intuitive.

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t)
{
    t = &another_variable; // ok
}

f(px);
```

and

```
void f(T t)
{
    *t = 42; // not ok!
}

f(px); // secretly modifying `x` through a pointer to const...
```

Reference: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091825/constant-pointer-vs-pointer-on-a-constant-value) for pointer to const vs. const pointer differences