# Const pointer C++ Stroustrup

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

```
int count_x(const char* p, char x)
     // count the number of occurrences of x in p[]
     // p is assumed to point to a zero-terminated array of char (or to nothing)
{
     if (p==nullptr)
           return 0;
     int count = 0;
     for (; *p!=0; ++p)
           if (*p==x)
                 ++count;
     return count;
}
```

p is a pointer. The const means that the pointer cannot be modified. But in the for loop, there is ++p, which means the pointer is being iterated over/incremented to access the values *p

There’s a contradiction there - p cannot be modified yet it is being incremented/modified?

Comment: No, the `const` means the thing pointer at can't be modified. You can still change the pointer.

Comment: That const means that what `p` points to is const, not `p` itself. The const would need to be on the other side of the `*` for what you describe.

Comment: @mrunion no, it does not.

Comment: @Swodrfish -- yes you are correct. I had misstated the reason and removed my post as it was incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why you felt it necessary to include Stroustrup's name in your question..

Comment: Also see [What is the difference between char * const and const char *?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/890535/608639), [constant pointer vs pointer on a constant value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10091825/608639) and friends.

Comment: @user3738870 The code is from *A Tour of C++* by Stroustrup.

Comment: @malpomene Thanks, so it basically denotes the author of the code in question right?

Answer (score 2):

Declarations in C++ are read from right to left. So something like

```
const char* p
```

would read: `p` is a non-const pointer to a `const char`.

Evidently, `p` is not `const`, but what it points to is `const`. So `*p = 's'` is illegal, but `p++` is not.

Comment: Wouldn't (const char)* p make more sense if that's what the line meant? Then how do you declare the pointer itself as const?

Comment: @user3180 `char *const p`.